# Ajillion PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class Update command

Tags: php, class, mysqli

Using the MySQLi class made by Ajillion :: https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

I would like to execute the following command

```
$command = "UPDATE sessions SET active = 0 WHERE DATE_ADD(last, INTERVAL life MINUTE) <= now()";
```

and I'm not sure how to do it with the class. Is there a way I can manage WHERE statements like this using that class, especially for UPDATE commands since normal queries I can $mysqli->rawQuery() the command.

The problem with running rawQuery() on the command above is that I get a

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_field() on a non-object

since it is trying to gather the results that an UPDATE command doesn't give.

Comment: This issue has been resolved: [Git Pull](https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/pull/24)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has appeared to solve the issue.

change line 101

```
$this->_query = filter_var($query, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

to

```
$this->_query = $this->_mysqli->real_escape_string($query);
```

I then went on to add

```
if(gettype($meta) == "boolean") return $results;
```

after line 401

There may be a better way to do this but this is what I did and it seems to work.