# php ajillion mysqli class quoted error

Tags: php, github, mysqli

I'm using [ajillion](https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class) mysqli class and I face error if I try to insert on quoted imploded 
I have been reading the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429929/ajillion-php-mysqli-database-class-update-command) but in my case did not helped
 the query what I try to execute looks as it follows

```
  function add_quotes($str) {
        return sprintf('"%s"', $str);
    }

    public function updateCategory($ids, $new_cat_name) {

     $imploded = implode(',',array_map(array($this,'add_quotes'), $ids));
     $resutls = $this->db->query("UPDATE __cat_product SET category = ".$new_cat_name." WHERE product_id IN(". $imploded .")");
     echo $this->db->getSql();

    }
```

this one is the raw error output `Fatal error: Problem preparing query (UPDATE __cat_product`SET category = 1 WHERE product_id IN('1403172219','B6Q09EA#ABD','H4P04EA#ABD'....`

so the problem are qoutes if I revert the qoutes than the query is ok

the problems are caused by `filter_var($query, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)` I have been removing add used the passed `$query` but I would like to filter inputs and I search for  a filter which doesn't conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

you also have to quote $new_cat_name